# What Smarty plugin does the lang_print function belong to, and what does it do?

Tags: php, smarty

Hi guys I'm playing with Smarty. As I'm new to Smarty I have no good understanding of some functions, so my question could be silly.

I would like to know what the following tag/function does, it is not in the Smarty documentation, I is probably a function of a Smarty plugin:

```
{lang_print id=756}
{lang_print id=720}
{lang_print id=123}
{lang_print id=2343}
{lang_print id=34123}
{lang_print id=3342}
{lang_print id=2233}
```

What does this do? Please kindly explain it to me.

Comment: why people dont want to reply my question?any reason if any one have then plz tell me i will cure that

Comment: but im working on project which is already coded in smarty so i cant by pass it,

Comment: @Jeffrey That's like saying "stop using PHP, and we'll answer your PHP question". Not exactly helpful.

Comment: AFAIK, that function is not built into Smarty, so must be a plugin defined somewhere in the application/framework you are using. If your project is built on top of a generally available application/framework, you may be able to get help by tagging the question with that. (And it's definitely nothing to do with Javascript, so not sure what that tag's doing there)

Comment: Looks like an ugly mechanism for translatable strings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's good form to answer questions this old, But this might be helpful to someone with a similar problem:

The lang_print is not a native smarty function. Therefore it is a custom smarty plugin.  You need to find the php code for the custom plugin to determine what it does.

Plugins are stored in a folder defined in the $smarty->plugins_dir.  By default this is the 'plugins' folder underneath the smarty folder. http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.plugins.dir.tpl

Plugins are separate files with names based on the plugin name, according to a specific naming convention.  In this case the filename would be functions.lang_print.php  http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.naming.conventions.tpl

You can look at the plugin php code to determine what it does, by reading the code and using regular php debugging techniques. http://markonphp.com/6-debugging-tips-php-coders-should-know/  Debug logging using error_log is one of the most common ways due to the complexity of getting a php debugger to work in most environments.